# Save current progress without commit

Tags: git

Say I have a repo on GitHub or Bitbucket and I do some work in the office but before leaving I want to save the current state without committing (because too messy for example). How would I go about saving the current state so I can complete the work on another machine?

Comment: You have the option to `git stash`, but anything saved in a stash can't be transferred to other repos, unlike commits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd commit. If you want to share work, you need to commit your changes.

Just check out a temporary branch for your new commit. So long as you're the only person working on it, you're free to squash the branch into a single commit before you merge into your main branch later on.

Answer (score 0):

Use feature branches for your day-to-day work. Commit and push at the end of the day. Then, when you are ready merge your branch back to the trunk.